# DataNucleus and Cache Coordination

Tags: java, caching, jpa, jdo, datanucleus

Does DataNucleus support Cache Coordination? If yes, how can I enable and use it?

I'm not actively using DataNucleus yet, but I want to consider it, if it supports Cache Coordination.

Background: Cache coordination is used by multiple cache instances to inform each other about changed entities (e. g. via JMS or RMI). Its purpose is to reduce the number of failed or repeated transactions (similar to what e. g. EclipseLink [provides](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_Cache_%28ELUG%29#Cache_Coordination_2)?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but from what I can read in the documentation about [JPA Caching](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_1/jpa/cache.html) or [JDO Caching](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_1/jdo/cache.html), the DataNucleus built-in implementations for Level 2 caching (the internal *weak* and *soft* reference based L2 caches) do not support distributed caching so no coordination when using them. But you can use one of the other pluggable implementations that might offer this option (Oracle Coherence does for example).

Comment: Thanks, Pascal. I'll probably use EclipseLink then - As long as there isn't any additional plugin which can provide the feature for DataNucleus (JDO/JPA).

Comment: @chris_l: You're welcome. Just to clarify (maybe I didn't express myself clearly), my understanding is that DN does have a plugin for at least one cache providing this feature (Coherence). I'm actually pretty sure Andy will show up to give you a fully accurate answer, especially if I made some mistakes.